# Why is there a Flash of Unstyled Text in Chrome?

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome, webfonts, google-fonts

I have an html doc with various scripts and stylesheets and google fonts etc, that is *mostly* optimized to prevent the display of any unstyled content.  Relevant bits:

```
      <head>
        <title>my site</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="/static/index.css">
        <script defer src="/static/shared.js"></script>
        <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
        <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Wire+One&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
        <style type="text/css">.fouc-hidden {display: none}</style>
        <script type="text/javascript">
          document.querySelector("html").classList.add("fouc-hidden")
          window.onload = () => {
            document.fonts.ready.then(() => {
              setTimeout(() => {
                console.log('done waiting')
                document.querySelector("html").classList.remove("fouc-hidden")
              }, 5000)
            })
          }
        </script>
      </head>
      <body>
        /* there is text stuff here, I thought that was assumed */
      </body>
```

so I:

1. request all font styles, other stylesheets and scripts
2. set a style for the `.fouc-hidden` class
3. add that class to the `html` element
4. wait for `window.onload` AND `document.fonts.ready` AND then another 5 seconds, and there is *STILL* a flash of text in the wrong font that happens right as I remove the `fouc-hidden` class.

NOTE all other styles (specifically colors) are applied by the time I reveal the page content.  I.e. it's doesn't seem to be a general flash of unstyled content issue, rather, unstyled fonts specifically

Why is this happening (Chrome specifically), and is there a way around it?

I'm not using any frameworks so pls any solutions in vanilla js!

Comment: Perhaps add a couple of div or some such in the body to "show" it right here as a snippet

Comment: You add the class on the `<html>`  when the JS first runs then when you remove it the document has to reflow the entire document which is why you see the "flash"

Comment: Did you mean to use `preload` here for things? ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/rel/preload

Comment: The crux of your question refers to something styled with "font" yet you don't illustrate anything related to that in your question (no elements that have any "flow" and certainly no CSS with font style.

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss I just copied the links that google fonts provided

Comment: I think what you are trying to work around is FOUT i.e.  FOUT uses a system font until the font is loaded which is a font loading strategy in the browser.  Thus my "preload" comment and reference may help you preload those fonts and the deal with the flash without this JS (I have not tried this to be fair here)

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss ah I gotcha - yea FWIW I did try that and the flash was still there - your earlier comment I think hit the nail on the head more than anything I've read so far

Answer (score 0):

The `.fouc-hidden` isn't applied until your script adds it, so you're showing the unstyled html until your script hides it. You need to add it to the raw html so it is there from the very beginning, then remove with the script:

```
<html class="fouc-hidden">
  <head>
    <title>my site</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="/static/index.css">
    <script defer src="/static/shared.js"></script>
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Wire+One&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <style type="text/css">.fouc-hidden {display: none}</style>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      window.onload = () => {
        document.fonts.ready.then(() => {
          setTimeout(() => {
            console.log('done waiting')
            document.querySelector("html").classList.remove("fouc-hidden")
          }, 5000)
        })
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    ....
  </body>
<html>
```

Comment: It is perhaps still going to reflow when he removes the class but since the question does not really have any thing styled with "font" which is the crux of the question it is hard to tell here with any certainty..

Comment: @jmoerdyk I avoided this approach because I read that this makes it so that users who do not have javascript enabled will never see the page at all - hence, hide via script, unhide via script, noscript means always visible

Answer (score 0):

I owe @MarkSchultheiss for this:

changing the style declaration for `.fouc-hidden` to `{visibility: hidden}` (instead of `{display: none}` seems to have solved it